# Casting List of derived class to List of base class still returning objects of derived class

Tags: c#, derived-class, base-class

I have the following code:

```
public class BaseClass
{
    public string A { get; set; }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public string B { get; set; }
}


List<DerivedClass> _derivedClass = new List<DerivedClass>() 
                                       { 
                                           new DerivedClass() 
                                             { A = "test1",
                                               B = "test2"
                                             }
                                       }; 

List<BaseClass> _baseClass = _derivedClass.Cast<BaseClass>.ToList();
```

The code compiles without any error, however, I expected `_baseClass` to only contain Property `A` (object of type `BaseClass`), but it's return both `A` and `B` properties (objects of type `DerivedClass`). What am I missing and what's the correct way to convert a List of a derived class to a list of its base class?

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you care if it's _really_ a `DerivedClass` behind the scenes?

Comment: How are you accessing these properties? It seems fine to me...

Comment: Hi guys, see my response to @ReedCopsey below. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> What am I missing and what's the correct way to convert a List of a derived class to a list of its base class?

The list still contains instances of the `DerivedClass`, but they are being used as references to the `BaseClass`.

Any consumer of this API will not know this, however, so they would see this as `BaseClass` elements.

This is common, and typically the correct approach.  If you needed to actually *convert* the instances to `BaseClass` instances (which is likely not necessary), you would need to actually make new `BaseClass` instances from the `DerivedClass` members, ie:

```
List<BaseClass> _baseClass = _derivedClass.Select(dc => new BaseClass {A = dc.A}).ToList();
```

That is typically not necessary, and your current approach is likely fine.   The [Liskov substitution principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle) states that any `DerivedClass` should be usable in any situation as a `BaseClass`, which means just returning the list as you did should be fine.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response. That makes sense and your solution worked. Long story short, I'm building an API layer using MVC 4 Web API and the serializer was including properties from the derived class instead of just the base class. The payload size was too big and I was trying to reduce the amount of data being sent back to the client.